# How to triple the amount every other time?

Tags: python

I don't know how to triple the amount.

1st month's payment 1   dollar.

2nd month's payment 2   dollars. (doubled the amount)

3rd month's payment 6   dollars. (triple it every other months)

4th month's payment 12  dollars. (double the amount)

5th month's payment 36  dollars. (triple it every other month)

6th month's payment 72  dollars. (double the amount)

7th month's payment 216 dollars. (triple it every other month)
and so on ...

I'm using the for and if statements.

```
base = 1
payments = int(input("For how many months did they say you will receive payments? "))


for i in range(0, payments):
  if i % 2 > 0:
    base *= 3 
  else:
    base *= 2 

  month = "Month " + str(i + 1) + ":" + str(base)
  print(month)
```

for month 1 I get $2 and I expect to get $1

Comment: "for month 1 I get $2 and I expect to get $1" Why? Does the multiplication inside the loop happen before or after the `print`? Therefore, will a multiplication occur before the first time you print? Trace through the logic.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator and on every odd entry, triple the amount.

```
  base = 1
  payments = 5
  print("Month 1: %s" % base)
  for i in range(2, payments):
    if i % 2 == 1:
      base *= 3
    else:
      base *= 2
  print("Month %s: %s" % (i+1, base))
```

Comment: I don't understand it

Comment: So understanding how the modulus operation works is key on this. You can use the wiki link to check it out. We know that we need to switch between doubling and tripling every other month, we can relate this "switching" of even, and odd numbers (numbers that don't divide evenly by 2) as we count. The modulus operator is the tool that finds the remainder after division of one number by another

Answer (score 0):

**You can use a list of numbers to be multiplied for (2 and 3), while the installments are less than the input. The logic is to alternate between the two numbers of the list, while the condition is true:**

```
base = 1
payments = input("For how many months did they say you will receive payments? ")
x = 1
multiplyList = [2, 3]

print(f'Month {x}: $ {base}')

while x <= int(payments):
    i = 0
    for number in multiplyList:
        base = (base * multiplyList[i])
        print(f'Month {x}: $ {base}')
        i = i + 1
        x = x + 1

# output:
# Month 1: $ 1
# Month 1: $ 2
# Month 2: $ 6
# Month 3: $ 12
# Month 4: $ 36
# Month 5: $ 72
# Month 6: $ 216
# Month 7: $ 432
# Month 8: $ 1296
# Month 9: $ 2592
# Month 10: $ 7776
```

Comment: month 1 should be $ 1

Comment: @hewiepx1 - forgot one detail, so I updated it again

Answer (score 0):

> **EDIT**: OP has edited the question to incorporate new attempts and
>   change the problem statement, so this is out of date.

As mentioned in other answers, your approach has a few drawbacks which make it non-ideal as a solution.

That being said, here is where the code went wrong:

Starting with a condensed version of your original:

```
base = 1
payments = 10
for i in range(payments):
  month = "Month " + str(i + 1) + ":" + str(base)
  base *= 2
  if i in range(2, payments, 3):
    base *= 3 
  print(month)
```

you need to end up here:

```
base = 1
payments = 10
for i in range(payments):
  month = "Month " + str(i + 1) + ":" + str(base)
  if i in range(1, payments, 3):
    base *= 3 
  else:
    base *= 2
  print(month)
```

The changes needed are:

- Using `range(2, ...)` instead of `range(1, ...)`.  This is because the way that you print and calculate you end up determining the new base during the previous month.
- Moving `*= 2` into an `else:` statement so you don't multiply by 6

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
base = 1
payments = int(input("For how many months did they say you will receive payments? "))
month = "Month " + str(1) + ":" + str(base)
print(month)
for i in range(1, payments):
  if i % 2 > 0:
    base *= 2 
  else:
    base *= 3 

  month = "Month " + str(i + 1) + ":" + str(base)
  print(month)
```

Because you were enetering straight into the `for` loop, it meant that you were doubling the first month. However if you print the first amount before the loop, start the loop at two, and swap the modulo statements around, it works.

Answer (score 0):

This solution has only one print() statement to print month and amount, but it has an `if == 0 in the loop`

you could get rid of the if statement within the loop but had to add one more print line before the loop.

if you don't want to print intermediate results then you can start the range from 1, get ird of the `if i == 0` and print the result after having left the for loop.

```
base = 1
payments = int(input("For how many months did they say you will receive payments? "))


print(base)
for i in range(0, payments):
    if i == 0:
        pass
    elif i % 2 > 0:
        base *= 2
    else:
        base *= 3
    msg = "Month " + str(i + 1) + ":" + str(base)
    print(msg)
```